# PHP can include 'filename' but c#?

Tags: c#, php, include, require, summary

i want like PHP summary codes in one files and repeat other pages c# . for ex in PHP :

include 'filename';
or
require 'filename';

thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do is extremely non-idiomatic. Instead, just make your "pages" a proper functions and call to them.

Comment: @arrowd could you please [edit] the question since you seem to understand what OP is trying to achieve?

Comment: so you're trying to use c# like if it were php. i don't think that's a wise move. it's like using a hacksaw as if it were a drill - you _may_ succeed with a decent amount of tinkering, but you won't be happy with the result.

Comment: thanks my friends. I work in a programming company ..Which has many tables for Repository. Which causes congestion and increased page load. So with my previous knowledge of PHP, I wanted to optimize and summarize the pages. any way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such in c# , but you can create class and write method contain on code that need to repeat .
example :

```
class MyClass
{
    //constructor
    public MyClass()
    {

    }
    public void func()
    {
        //code that repeat here 
    }
}
```

then declare instance from this class and call function

Comment: yes we can.. but I have a lot of Repository.. How to use it in summary form??